# Punctuation not detected between words with no space

Tags: python, regex

How can I split sentences, when punctuation is detected (.?!) and occurs between two words without a space?

***Example:***

```
>>> splitText = re.split("(?<=[.?!])\s+", "This is an example. Not 
    working as expected.Because there isn't a space after dot.")
```

output:

```
['This is an example.', 
"Not working as expected.Because there isn't a space after dot."]
```

expected:

```
['This is an example.', 
'Not working as expected.', 
'Because there isn't a space after dot.']`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
splitText = re.split("[.?!]\s*", "This is an example. Not working as expected.Because there isn't a space after dot.")
```

+ is used for 1 or more of something, * for zero of more.

if you need to keep the . you probably don't want to split, instead you could do:

```
splitText = re.findall(".*?[.?!]", "This is an example. Not working as expected.Because there isn't a space after dot.")
```

which gives

```
['This is an example.',
 ' Not working as expected.',
 "Because there isn't a space after dot."]
```

you can trim those by playing with the regex (eg `'\s*.*?[.?!]'`) or just using `.trim()`

Comment: @zppinto yeah, i just noticed that, edited the answer.

Comment: If you look at the documentation of [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) there is a note that mentions that split doesn't work on empty matches, that's the reason `(?<=[.?!])\s*`doesn't work if there is no space.

Comment: @SebastianProske Oh that's bad :( Any solution with other method?

Comment: @zppinto use findall instead of split, adding to my answer

Comment: This solution won't work if there are common abbreviations like `Mr.`, `etc.` inside the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
https://regex101.com/r/icrJNl/3/.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

split_text = re.findall(".*?[?.!]", "This is an example! Working as "
                        "expected?Because.")

pprint(split_text)
```

Note: `.*?` is a lazy (or non-greedy) quantifier in opposite to `.*` which is a greedy quantifier.

Output:

```
['This is an example!', 
 ' Working as expected?', 
 'Because.']
```

Another solution:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

split_text = re.split("([?.!])", "This is an example! Working as "
    "expected?Because.")

pprint(split_text)
```

Output:

```
['This is an example', 
'!', 
' Working as expected', 
'?', 
'Because', 
'.', 
'']
```

Comment: It works, but I lost the punctuation and that is not a solution for me. @SebastianProske has made the point... This can't be done with `split`